# Complex If Statements VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, for-loop

All,

I have the below conditional formatting rule. I would like to use to extract data onto another worksheet (CM) if the conditional formatting for the cell is TRUE.

However reading several forums it has become apparent that VBA cannot detect when a conditional formatted cell is "TRUE".

Alternatively as a work around I would like to place the below statement into a an if statement. (My conditional formatting statements)

I have two conditional format statements 
1st in the hierarchy is; (Displaying red)

=AND(F1>D1,OR((S1/D1)>=1.15,T1>=200000))

2nd in the hierarchy is;(Displaying Orange)

=F1>D1

Can anyone suggest the way of doing this. (I seem to struggle with placing AND / OR statements into VBA)

```
Dim LR As Long
LR = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
For X = 9 To LR Step 1
If Range("F" & X).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 OR Range("F" & X).Interior.ColorIndex = 45 Then

Dim LR1 As Long
LR1 = CM.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
RP.Range("B" & X, "D" & X).Copy
CM.Range("A" & LR1 + 1, "C" & LR1 + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

RP.Range("S" & X, "T" & X).Copy
CM.Range("D" & LR1 + 1, "E" & LR1 + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Else
End If
Next X
```

Also is there a way of telling which part of the IF statement is true as I would like to Tick a box "Critical" if the Red condition is met and "Non Critical" if the amber condition is met.

Picture added for context
[image]

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comments you can get the Conditional Format Color with `DisplayFormat`.

Also it is recommended that one skips the clipboard when only wanting values and assign the values directly:

```
Dim LR As Long
Dim LR1 As Long
LR = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
For x = 9 To LR Step 1
    If Range("F" & x).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Or Range("F" & x).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 45 Then
        LR1 = CM.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
        CM.Range("A" & LR1 + 1, "C" & LR1 + 1).value = RP.Range("B" & x, "D" & x).value
        CM.Range("D" & LR1 + 1, "E" & LR1 + 1).value = RP.Range("S" & x, "T" & x).value
    End If
Next x
```

If you want to avoid the color test, Your two formulas have one thing in common `=F1>D1`

It will return true whenever this is true.  The first formula is a more specific form but still is dependent on this.

So we only need to test that one.

```
Dim LR As Long
Dim LR1 As Long
LR = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
For x = 9 To LR Step 1
    If Range("F" & x).value > Range("D" & x).value Then
        LR1 = CM.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
        CM.Range("A" & LR1 + 1, "C" & LR1 + 1).value = RP.Range("B" & x, "D" & x).value
        CM.Range("D" & LR1 + 1, "E" & LR1 + 1).value = RP.Range("S" & x, "T" & x).value
    End If
Next x
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Scott Craner's answer and it's probably the better way to go.

You asked if it was possible to determine whether a conditional format had resolved to `True`, and the answer is yes it is possible. The difficulty is that Excel has some complex conditional formatting rules and you'd need a fair bit of coding to cover every scenario. The code below shows how to handle probably the most common one (ie the cell value test, as in your question), but I've left scope for you to expand it if you wish.

I guess this type of approach would be handy if you kept changing your format condition rules, as this code would adopt those new rules:

```
Public Function EvaluatedFormatCondition(cell As Range) As Boolean
    Dim item As Object
    Dim res As Boolean

    For Each item In cell.FormatConditions
        If TypeOf item Is FormatCondition Then
            Select Case item.Type
                Case xlCellValue
                    Select Case item.Operator
                        Case xlEqual
                            res = (cell.Value = Evaluate(item.Formula1))
                        Case xlGreater
                            res = (cell.Value > Evaluate(item.Formula1))
                        Case xlLess
                            res = (cell.Value < Evaluate(item.Formula1))
                        Case xlGreaterEqual
                            res = (cell.Value >= Evaluate(item.Formula1))
                        Case xlLessEqual
                            res = (cell.Value < Evaluate(item.Formula1))
                        Case xlNotEqual
                            res = (cell.Value <> Evaluate(item.Formula1))
                        Case xlBetween
                            res = (cell.Value >= Evaluate(item.Formula1) And cell.Value <= Evaluate(item.Formula2))
                        Case xlNotBetween
                            res = (cell.Value < Evaluate(item.Formula1) Or cell.Value > Evaluate(item.Formula2))
                    End Select
            End Select
            If res And item.StopIfTrue Then
                EvaluatedFormatCondition = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
    EvaluatedFormatCondition = res
End Function
```